# I am trying to do child Fluent Validation in Blazor models,Which is not working fine

Tags: c#, blazor, fluentvalidation

i am doing the FluentValidation for my classes in the blazor project.
model and validation classes are as shown bellow.

```
public class A{
public string  Afield1 { get; set; }
public string  Afield2 { get; set; }
public List<B> Bs { get; set; } 

}

public class B{
public string  Bfield1 { get; set; }
public string  Bfield2 { get; set; }

}


public class AValidator : AbstractValidator<A>
{
        public AValidator()
        {
         RuleFor(s => s.Afield1).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Select The Afield1");
         RuleForEach(s => s.Bs).SetValidator(new BValidator());
        }
}

public class BValidator : AbstractValidator<B>
{
        public BValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(s => s.Bfield1).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Select Bfield1");
          
        }
}
```

i want to do some complex validation.
If the Afield2 in A have the value "KI" , then only i want validation message to be set for Bfield2 of B

i tried bellow code which is not working

```
 RuleFor(s => s.Bs).Custom((c, e) => 
        {
            if (e.InstanceToValidate.Afield2 == "KI")
            {
                if (c.Any(a=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Bfield2)))
                {
                    e.AddFailure("Bfield2 not entered");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: *If the Afield2 in A have the value "KI"*, shouldn't that use `==` instead of `!=`? `e.InstanceToValidate.Afield2 == "KI"`

Comment: That was mistack in my quesion.i have tried that still not working,i think that whether i need to try dufferent way

Comment: No Repro. Your code works on my PC. That means it's a good [mre], +1.